# Пользовательская функция Excel для отправки данных по HTTP

Tags: http, vba

В VBA опыта нет, но готов разобраться, если будет общее направление, куда копать.
Итак, задача в общих чертах:

1. В панели управления (например во вкладке "Данные") нужна кнопка "Отправить данные"
2. По нажатии этой кнопки скрипт проверяет формат листа (в правильных ли ячейках расположены те или иные данные) и если формат верен, то отправляет данные по HTTP на эндпоинт API.

Насколько я понимаю, VBA-скрипт (или макрос) может храниться только в контексте книги. Поэтому основной вопрос такой: можно ли создать описанную выше функцию в глобальном контексте Ecxel?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю сам: нужно использовать надстройку. Для таких дилетантов, как я: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofmXa0-hu3k